# The following packages are not available from current channels: - yfinance

Tags: python-3.x, yfinance

I try to install yfinance into anaconda, using command: 
conda install -c anaconda yfinance

error message shows:
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- yfinance

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I have also used:
conda config --append channels conda-forge

nothing changes

conda install -c anaconda yfinance
conda config --append channels conda-forge

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the `pip install yfinance` command instead of `conda install`